# When should I initialize Golang variables

Tags: variables, go

There are some kind of variables in Golang:

1. global variable: `var a int`
2. local variable: `func hello() { var a int }`
3. return variable: `func hello() (a int) {}`

Golang sometimes will auto-init some variables,
but I don't know when and why? It confused me.

Example:

```
type User struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

func foo(bts []byte) {
  var a User
  err := json.Unmarshal(bts, &a)  // It's ok
}

func bar(bts []byte) (a *User) {
  err := json.Unmarshal(bts, a) // It will crash
}
```

which one should I have to initialize before use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Golang will init all variables (not <strike>sometimes</strike>, not <strike>some</strike>):

In your code:

```golang
func bar(bts []byte) (a *User) {
  err := json.Unmarshal(bts, a) // It will crash
}
```

You passed a nil pointer but you need a value pointed to by `a` , not a nil pointer:
So you may create a Value then store the address of this Value inside `a`:

---

When you use `var a *User` or `func bar(bts []byte) (a *User)`:
The `a` is a pointer to the `User` type, and it is initialized to it's zero value, which is `nil`,
see ([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TexE3uCzQI)):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var a *User
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n\n", a)    
}

type User struct {
    Name string `json:"Name"`
    Age  int    `json:"Age"`
}
```

output:

```
(*main.User)(nil)
```

---

And You may use `a = &User{}` to initialize it, like this working code ([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ubUYufOjfq)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func foo(bts []byte) (*User, error) {
    var a User
    err := json.Unmarshal(bts, &a) // It's ok
    return &a, err
}

func bar(bts []byte) (a *User, err error) {
    a = &User{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(bts, a) // It's ok
    return
}
func main() {
    str := `{ "Name": "Alex", "Age": 3 }`
    u, err := foo([]byte(str))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n\n", u) // &main.User{Name:"Alex", Age:3}

    u, err = bar([]byte(str))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n\n", u) // &main.User{Name:"Alex", Age:3}

}

type User struct {
    Name string `json:"Name"`
    Age  int    `json:"Age"`
}
```

output:

```
&main.User{Name:"Alex", Age:3}

&main.User{Name:"Alex", Age:3}
```

---

[Variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations):

> A variable declaration creates one or more variables, binds
> corresponding identifiers to them, **and gives each a type and an
> initial value.**

[The initial value (zero value)](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value):

> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a declaration
> or a call of `new`, or when a `new` value is created, either through a
> composite literal or a call of `make`, and no explicit initialization is
> provided, the variable or value is given a default value. Each element
> of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for its type:
> `false` for booleans, `0` for integers, `0.0` for floats, `""` for strings,
> **and `nil` for pointers**, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and
> maps. This initialization is done recursively, so for instance each
> element of an array of structs will have its fields zeroed if no value
> is specified.

And see `func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error` Docs:

> Unmarshal parses the JSON-encoded data and stores the result in the
> value pointed to by v.

Answer (score 4):

Go is a very consistent language: [it *always* automatically initializes variables:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables)

> A variable's value is retrieved by referring to the variable in an expression; it is the most recent value assigned to the variable. If a variable has not yet been assigned a value, its value is the zero value for its type.

[The zero value is:](https://tour.golang.org/basics/12)

> `0` for numeric types,
>
> `false` for the boolean type, and
>
> `""` (the empty string) for strings.

In the case of maps, slices, pointers, and interfaces, the zero value is `nil`.

For custom types, [it is idiomatic](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/01/19/what-is-the-zero-value-and-why-is-it-useful) (i.e. generally considered best practice) to make the zero value useful somehow, usually as a default value or important sentinel.

---

Edit: your example [does not crash.](https://play.golang.org/p/leSnANRiUO) Maybe one of the things you removed from it was causing the crash instead?

Comment: Sorry for the example, i use interface just as a placeholder, the real one is a custom structure